# How to call Java method from Play Framework 2.5.X

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.3, morris.js

1. I have a JavaScript file `morris.js` and I have to call some Java methods to retrieve a `map` or `list` result. I can't use reverserouting or controllers methods because I must return `Result` type within the controllers.

   How can I achieve this?

   An example of the expected result:

   ```
   $.ajax(some method)
         .done(some treatment)
         .fail(console.log('not ok'));

   // data stolen from http://howmanyleft.co.uk/vehicle/jaguar_'e'_type

   var tax_data = [
      {"period": "2013", "licensed": 400, "sorned": 550},
      {"period": "2012", "licensed": 450, "sorned": 400},
      {"period": "2011", "licensed": 350, "sorned": 550},
      {"period": "2010", "licensed": 500, "sorned": 700},
      {"period": "2009", "licensed": 250, "sorned": 380},
      {"period": "2008", "licensed": 350, "sorned": 240},
      {"period": "2007", "licensed": 180, "sorned": 300},
      {"period": "2006", "licensed": 300, "sorned": 250},
      {"period": "2005", "licensed": 200, "sorned": 150}
   ];
   ```
2. I have a method with a parameter in controllers. How can I add it into JavaScript router:

   ```
   public Result getYearUploadedVideos(Long userId){
       // ...
   }
   ```

   my router:

   ```
   public Result jsRoutes() {
       return ok(play.routing.JavaScriptReverseRouter.create("jsRoutes",
                 routes.javascript.Signup.forgotPassword(),
                 routes.javascript.AdminManagement.contact(),
                 routes.javascript.ProfilManagement.view(),
                 routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getYearUploadedVideos()))
           .as("text/javascript");
   }
   ```

... but it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In fact very easy :

```
public Result jsRoutes() {
    return ok(
            play.routing.JavaScriptReverseRouter.create("jsRoutes",
                    routes.javascript.Signup.forgotPassword(),
                    routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getSmartCasterSharedDonutStatDataJson(),
                    routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getSmartCasterActionStatDataJson(),
                    routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getUploadedPublishedVideoStatDataJson(),
                    routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getVideoSharedDonutStatDataJson(),
                    routes.javascript.DashboardManagement.getVideoActionStatDataJson()))
            .as("text/javascript");

}
```

then :

```
$.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardManagement.getVideoSharedDonutStatDataJson(id))
    .done(function(donut){ 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(donut));
...});
```

that's it we do not configured ID in reverse JS routing